# How to transform a string of 0s and 1s into a boolean array

Tags: c#, arrays

Basically, the title says what I'd like to do.

I have a string such as the following.

```
1 0 1 0 1
0 0 0 0 0
1 0 0 0 1
0 0 0 0 0
1 0 1 0 1
```

I'd like to convert this into a 2-dimensional boolean array (obviously, `0 -> false` and `1 -> true`). My current approach is removing non-linebreak-whitespace, then iterating through the lines of the string.

This leaves me with transforming a string such as `10101` into a boolean array of `true, false, true, false, true`. Now, I'm hoping that there are pre-existing methods to do this conversion - using Java, I'm pretty sure it could be done using the `streams` API, but unfortunately, I'm not that adept with C# yet.

---

Hence, my question: Are there existing methods to do this conversion in a compact way? Or do I have to manually iterate over the string and do a `== 0`/`==1` comparison for each character?

Comment: Is that "box" a single string(with spaces and line breaks)? And what output are you trying to generate?

Comment: Why do you think, there´s an existing solution that converts a 2d-string-box into a 2dim bool-box? I doubt anyone before did this, but I´m pretty sure you can do it yourself. Anway this question asks for libraries/docs, which is off-topic here.

Comment: @HimBromBeere I was hoping it's in the standard libraries, as is the case in Java.

Comment: I'm curious, what Java method(s) are you referring to? This seems like an awfully specific use case.

Comment: well, the general case would be taking a list of `A`, processing them in some way, and returning the resulting list of `B`. As far as I know, that's what `.map` does.

Comment: Do you know about linq? it is an standar way to work with lists, including strings.

Comment: I know the notation (assuming that it's identical to java's lambdas, which it seems to be), I was pretty much mainly looking for the method that allows me to *use* it to transform one list into another.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Single string

If you have a a string like "10101", you can use LINQ to convert it to a bit array.

```
string input = "10101";
bool[] flags = input.Select( c => c == '1' ).ToArray();
```

### Array of strings

LINQ doesn't work so well with two-dimensional arrays, but it works fine with jagged arrays. If a `bool[][]` will do, this solution should work:

```
string[] input = { "10101","01010" };

bool[][] flags = input.Select
(
    s => s.Select
    ( 
        c => c == '1'
    )
    .ToArray()
)
.ToArray();
```

Comment: If I am not wrong the OP wants a two dimensional array of boolan (ie rows and columns) from the original 'box'

Comment: @Steve true, but as mentioned in the 2nd- and 3rd-last paragraphs of my question, I'm iterating over the lines of the string and can then use this solution. I suppose you could somehow also do the whole thing as a one-liner, but I'd like to be able to maintain my code as well.

Comment: @PixelMaster its not the answer to what you're requesting is it now? ;)

Comment: @PixelMaster, if it helps, my answer does return a `bool[][]`.

Comment: Edited the answer to include an example that works with an array of strings.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a relatively ugly "one-liner":

```
string input = "1 0 1 0 1\n0 0 0 0 0\n1 0 0 0 1\n0 0 0 0 0\n1 0 1 0 1";
bool[][] flags = input.Split(new[] { "\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None) // Split into lines, e.g. [ "1 0 1 0 1", "0 0 0 0 0" ]
                      .Select(line => line.Split(' ') // Split each line into array of "1"s or "0"s
                                          .Select(num => num == "1").ToArray()) // Project each line into boolean array
                      .ToArray(); // Get array of arrays
```

But here is an (arguably more readable) version that probably comes closer to what I suspect is your actual use case, e.g. reading a line from the user one at a time.

```
string input = "1 0 1 0 1\n0 0 0 0 0\n1 0 0 0 1\n0 0 0 0 0\n1 0 1 0 1";

List<bool[]> boolArrays = new List<bool[]>();

string[] lines = input.Split(new[] { "\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
foreach (string line in lines) // Could be a different loop that gets lines from the user, e.g. `do { var s = Console.ReadLine(); doMore(); } while (s != null);`
{
    string[] charsAsStrings = line.Split(' '); // TODO: Improve variable names
    bool[] arrayRow = charsAsStrings.Select(numString => numString == "1").ToArray(); // Parsing to int would be pointless
    boolArrays.Add(arrayRow);
}

bool[][] flags = list.ToArray();
```

---

As noted in the comments, you typically want to use [Environment.NewLine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.newline%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) rather than  `"\n"`. Note that we can't split by a string without providing an entire array -- though that can be solved with [extension methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods).

Comment: The first one is good. You could also consider that the lines might be separated with an `Environment.Newline`.

Comment: @Jimi | True, and that often is what I do -- largely because I think it's easier to read. I figured there's no point, as I highly doubt OP would actually be declaring a multiline verbatim string like that. What's wrong with the second method?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the second method. If I had to say something about it, it's probably redundant because the first one already gets the jog done without unnecessary conversions.

Comment: @Jimi To the best of my knowledge, all the steps in the second version are still done in the first, just not as obviously.

Comment: That's why I said *redundant* :) Anyway, Linq methods can be cached, and performace will greatly improve thanks to this feature. A List conversion is not.

Comment: @Jimi Good point. Personally, I would probably use the first method, but only if I had a multiline string to begin with, which I find unlikely -- I figure you're more likely to be operating a line at a time, which is why OP selected an answer that returns a 1D array.

Comment: I'm actually using neither `Environment.NewLine` nor `\n` or `\r\n`, I'm using a `StringReader` with `.ReadLine()`.

Comment: @PixelMaster Right, that's what I figured. But you did ask about a 2D array, so I figured I'd answer your explicit question first. The second method, like my answer says, is probably much closer to your actual use case.

Answer (score 2):

Similar answer @Sinjai's. This works though by utilizing the fact that a string can be `.Select`ed as a `char[]`.

```
var boolVals = yourString.Replace(" ","").Replace("\r","")
    .Split('\n').Select(x => x.Select(y => y == '1').ToArray()).ToArray();
```

This works with a scenario where you might or might not have \r\n and spaces between every 1 or 0. If you had a string that looked like this:

`string yourString = "10101\n10001";`

then the code would be even shorter:

```
var boolVals = yourString.Split('\n').Select(x => x.Select(y => y == '1').ToArray()).ToArray();
```

Comment: I'm curious, would splitting by `Environment.NewLine` negate the need to replace `\r` occurrences?

Comment: If you *knew* that you would always have whatever was the newline for the environment, then you could do that. However, that would also mean you need to use the overload of split that uses the `string[]` and `StringSplitOptions`. I liked this version though because it works with or without \r and with or without spaces.

Comment: Gotcha. This might be a time to avoid `var`, eh? Given the amount of chained `Select`s going on?

Answer (score 0):

Try using this function:

```
static List<bool> AsArray(string boolString)
{
    List<bool> toArray = new List<bool>();
    foreach (char boolChar in boolString)
    {
        if (boolChar == '0')
        {
            toArray.Add(false);
        }
        else if (boolChar == '1')
        {
            toArray.Add(true);
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception("String can only be made of 1 and 0.");
        }
    }
    return toArray;
}
```

Comment: OP asked for 2D bool array, not a list.

Comment: linq is a better, shorter and easier solution.

Answer (score -1):

The following does exactly what you want to a 5x5 bool array as an example.

## code

```
        string str = "1 0 1 0 1 " +
                     "0 0 0 0 1 " +
                     "0 1 1 1 0 " +
                     "1 0 1 0 1 " +
                     "1 1 1 1 1";

        string[] stringArray = str.Split(' '); // split strings into string array using "space" as split
        bool[,] boolArray = new bool[5, 5];

        int counter = 0;  // counter for iterating through stringArray
        int counterMax = stringArray.Length - 1; // set max for counter to stop index out of range


        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) // Y axis
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) // X axis
            {
                if (stringArray[counter] == "0")
                {
                    boolArray[j, i] = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    boolArray[j, i] = true;
                }
                if (counter < counterMax)
                {
                    counter++;
                }
                else
                {
                    break;
                }

            }
        }
```